# Find all views and tables that depend on an Oracle database table

Tags: database, oracle

Hi I have a database with a couple of schemas one of which has a Table `TABLE_NAME`. I need to make a change to the table and to do that I could do with knowing which tables and views in all the different schemas depend on it.

Its an oracle database, is there some SQL I can run that would help?

I've seen a couple of posts that suggest:

```
select OWNER, Name 
from dba_dependencies 
where type = 'VIEW' 
and REFERENCED_TYPE = 'TABLE' 
AND REFERENCED_NAME IN ('table_name', 'TABLE_NAME');
```

and

```
select * 
from all_constraints 
where r_constraint_name in (select constraint_name 
                            from all_constraints 
                            where table_name='TABLE_NAME')
```

Neither of which appear to be working, the first gives me a `"table or view does not exist"` on `dba_dependencies` and the second returns no results.

Comment: They should both work, but your login/account doesn't have permission to see the `dba_dependencies` table.

Comment: Try `all_Dependencies` instead of DBA.  May hide a few results from you though... DBA_Dependencies covers a greater scope; but as pointed out, requires higher privileges.